# Automation a file upload selenium IDE Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, upload, automation

i want to upload a file to a website for my course work but it doesn't have any INPUT tag like

```
"**//input[@type='file']**"
```

so i cann't just simply upload using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(filePath)
```

i just have a button

```
<a data-action="upload" title="Upload"></a>
```

.which open a OS popup when it get clicked 
and i know selenium can't handle it.

any suggestion would be appreciated

Edited
i check that it send JSON packet to some Url but how do i send such a request to URL using selenium because that must be send using the browser "Session Issue"

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using the **Autoit** but it platform oriented if you want to have a solution that can be used on every platform then use JavAuto and few line of code and thats it
you can google it or copy the link to search bar "javauto.org"

```
mouseClick("left", 50, 50);//this will leftclck the mouse and X,Y=50,50
send(filepath)//string /path/to/the/file
```

save it as .javauto file
then use this command to produce a java code

```
java -jar javauto yourfile.javauto
```

this will give you yourfile.java
then make a .class file using java complier

```
javac yourfile.java
```

this produce a yourfile.class
run that file to automate the result

note:
make sure your have JDK and JRE installed
and have all the file including the lib in one directory

sorry for bad English a bit week in it